# Enterprise WSDL and MFA

Tags: rest-api, wsdl

I use an enterprise WSDL to connect to Salesforce as API user Will this require MFA to connect in 2023? Is MFA required for my integration users? Details of MFA enablement can be found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000388806&type=1)

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in the [FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000388806&type=1):

> Is MFA required for my integration users?
>
> (This topic applies to products built on the Salesforce Platform
> only.)
>
> The MFA requirement doesn’t apply to system integration login types
> via the API.
>
> MFA is required if admins or anyone else logs in to integration user
> (also known as API user) accounts – even if it’s only to first set up
> the user or to perform occasional maintenance tasks such as changing
> passwords or updating security tokens. These types of users are often
> highly privileged, so it’s important to use MFA to protect human
> access to these accounts.
>
> To enable MFA for integration users, assign the Multi-Factor
> Authentication for User Interface Logins permission. Note that this
> permission applies only if someone logs in to the user account via the
> UI – REST or SOAP API calls aren’t affected.

In other words, as long as you don't try to log in through the UI, you won't be required to have MFA for these users. In addition, MFA will not be enforced as long as it is a SOAP- or REST-based connection.